# Invoke child component function

Tags: reactjs

```jsx
var popup = React.render(
              <PopUp>
                <Countdown />
              </PopUp>,
              document.getElementById('popup')
            );
```

The Countdown component is rendered in the Popup component as {this.props.children}

How can I call the Countdown component's `Stop` method?

Comment: Why are not countdown invoking the stop itself? What are the purpose of the countdown?  We need more information to be able to help you.

Comment: @magnudae A button click or some other event that is unrelated to Countdown component.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you should do it is to have another top-level component that handle all the state of your app and in your case have a callback function 'stop-countdown' that it is passed to your component Countdown like that:

```jsx
var popup = React.render(
              <PopUp>
                <Countdown handleStop={this.handleStop} />       
              </PopUp>,
              document.getElementById('popup')
            );
```

So now inside your Countdown component you call the **handleStop** function when it is time.

Comment: This makes it the other way around. Countdown doesn't call top-level component, top-level component or just plain javascript will call Countdown.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a prop `stopped`, which will allow the countdown to continue when false.

```
var stopped = true; // set value of stopped however you want
var popup = React.render(
  <PopUp>
    <Countdown stopped={stopped} />       
  </PopUp>,
  document.getElementById('popup')
);
```

within `Countdown`, you can check the value of stopped within the `componentWillReceiveProps` method:

```
var Countdown = React.createClass({
    componentWillRecieveProps: function(nextProps){
      if (this.props.stopped == nextProps.stopped){
        return; // do nothing if the value has not changed
      }
      if (nextProps.stopped){
        //call stop timer here
      }
      else {
        //start the timer here
      }
    },
    //getInitialState, render, and other methods
});
```